# Redirect Website Homepage Only

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have two different websites that are hosted on different servers. I would like to redirect the homepage of the old site (www.oldsite.com.au) to the homepage of the new site (newsite.com.au). However, I do **not** want any pages within the old site (www.oldsite.com.au/page) to redirect to the new one (newsite.com.au/page). So, www.oldsite.com.au must redirect to newsite.com.au, but any other pages or files within the old site must not redirect.

All the .htaccess ideas I've tried just redirect every file from the old site to the new one.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try one of these:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ http://newsite.com.au/
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://newsite.com.au/ [L,R=301]
```

If you don't want a 301 (permanent) redirect, remove the `301` from the RedirectMatch or the `=301` from the square brackets in the rule's flags.