# 301 redirects / htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Could someone help me please with 301s.  I'm moving a website to a new domain but it has a slightly different directory structure.

I've generated an .htaccess file with basic 301s, for example:

Redirect 301    /mypage1.html   https://www.mywebsite.com/mypage/1/

Redirect 301    /mypage2.html   https://www.mywebsite.com/mypage/2/

Redirect 301    /mypage3.html   https://www.mywebsite.com/mypage/3/

This works perfectly.  However, I cannot redirect the main homepage, as it seems to break all of my individual 301s.

So if I add:

Redirect 301    /   https://www.mywebsite.com

All of my single 301 redirects stop working.

Is there any way I can keep the working 301s and also redirect the homepage too?

Comment: The Redirect directive does _prefix_ matching - so everything after / will be appended to the substitution URL again by that last line you have shown. You can use RedirectMatch for this instead - that uses regular expressions, and does not work based on prefixes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect Website Homepage Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31281346/redirect-website-homepage-only)

Comment: Found the solution myself, I needed:

Redirect 301 /index.php https://www.mywebsite.com